# Renault Clio 1.2 2003 all the car does is clicks - Starting Issue

Tags: troubleshooting, starter, renault, clio

It cannot be jump started and the battery is ok.

***Can you help?***

I have a Renault Clio 2003 1.2 I have checked the battery, it's is ok. There is a clicking sound coming from the fuse box I think it is the starter relay.

***Can you give me your opinion and let me know which relay it may be or if you know what the problem may be?***

Answer (score 4):

Some possible causes for your problem:

1. Damaged wiring from starter relay to starter
2. Damaged wiring from battery to starter
3. Damaged wiring from ignition lock to starter relay
4. Broken starter relay

3 and 4 could be possible because the relay click you are hearing could come from a different relay. There is a relay in some cars to turn off other power loads like the radio to reduce the load at the battery during engine start.

5. Broken Starter
6. Dead battery

You said you checked the battery, so this is just for completeness. If the clicking sound you are hearing is a **continuos repeating clicking** while holding the key in 'start' position, it could come from a dead/weak battery. Some modern cars (mostly VAG but maybe also others) refuse to start when the battery is to weak. Instead you hear a repeating clicking sound.

7. Some problem with the anti-theft system

Usually some light in the dashboard should light up in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Without access to a wiring diagram you'll have to look at your owners manual or see if they put a diagram on the fuse/relay box.

Either way, if the starter relay is clicking you can rule out anti theft. The starter relay generally draws power from the ignition and passes power to the starter S terminal. If you're getting power at the S terminal the relay is OK and the starter is bad. If you're not getting power on the S terminal try switching the starter relay with another relay and or inspect the wiring.

More than likely, you need a new starter.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments I found the problem it was a bad earth between the gearbox and the chassis earth strap corroded through  I 're connected the wire using existing strap overlapping the earth strap . Good fix